# XPath - how to get a list of multiple tags with the same name

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<shop>
    <shoes>
        <brand>Nike</brand>
        <size>13</size>
        <colour>White</colour>
        <price>34.99</price>
        <additional name="abc">123</additional>
        <additional name="def">456</additional>
        <additional name="ghi">789</additional>
        <additional name="jkl">101</additional>
    </shoes>
    <trousers>
        <brand>Levi</brand>
        <size>36</size>
        <legSize>33</legSize>
        <colour>Stonewash</colour>
        <price>69.99</price>
        <additional name="mno">112</additional>
        <additional name="pqr">131</additional>
        <additional name="stu">415</additional>
        <additional name="vwx">161</additional>
    </trousers>
</shop>
```

Given the above xml file, how would I retrieve a list of all `<additional>` tags within the `<shoes>` tag? I want to get all the values of 'name' along with the numeric value between the tags. Something like this:

```
abc, 123
def, 456
ghi, 789
jkl, 101
```

The problem is I don't know how many additional tags there will be. There could be none and there could be 20. I need some way to count them all then strip out the information.

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: Hello JEY, I have tried "shop/shoes//additional[@name][1]" which gives me what I want for position one. I can't seem to find a way to return an array of everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses `XPath` from the JDK to execute a query.  It assumes that the variable `xml` contains your XML document.

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = factory.newXPath();
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//shoes/additional", new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)), XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
    String name = nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
    String text = nodeList.item(i).getTextContent();
    System.out.println(name + ", " + text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With //shoes/additional you would get a list of all the nodes and could iterate over it in Java.